# How can I get a variable from JS into MySql database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to save the variable from JS named count into my MySql database.

```
let count = 0;
countup.addEventListener("click", function() {
    count = count + 1;
    counter.innerText = count;
    let avgberechnung = count / 365;
    avg.innerText = avgberechnung + " Ø Köpfe am Tag";                       
},false);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Send it to PHP via an AJAX request (`fetch()`), then have the PHP code run the DB query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution with php server

1. Use ajax to send request

   $.post('save.php',{count:count})

   .done(function(data){

   alert("success -".data);

   });
2. Create a PHP file (here save.php) to save the post data.

helpful links

[Insert data into mysql database](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

[Jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you! This is my code now. Is it correct?

countup.addEventListener("click", function() {
        count = count + 1;
        counter.innerText = count;
        let avgberechnung = count / 365;
        avg.innerText = avgberechnung + " Ø Köpfe am Tag";        
        $.post('inc/save.php',{count:count})
        .done(function(data){
            alert("success -".data);
        });
    },false);